# What is the <A W3MIRHREF> tag in HTML?

Tags: html, hyperlink, xhtml, href

in a **.html** file I have found the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "html.dtd">
<HTML>

    <P><A W3MIRHREF="http://www.myCompany.org/division/subdivision/repec/handle/wpaper/wp-02-01.rdf" HREF="wp-02-01.rdf">wp-02-01.rdf</A></P>
</HTML>
```

What exactly mean the **W3MIRHREF** attribute? I never see it, I always say the classic  tag

What is this? and for what is used?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 2):

This attribute is added to a link by [w3mir](https://metacpan.org/pod/w3mir) utility:

> w3mir is a all purpose HTTP copying and mirroring tool. The main focus
>   of w3mir is to create and maintain a browsable copy of one, or
>   several, remote WWW site(s).

This particular attribute is used to store a link to the original document.

Comment: ... and had it been written 10 years later, it would have used a different name for the attribute; `data-w3mirhref` or something.

Answer (score 0):

The `W3MIRHREF` has no meaning in any HTML recommendation.

I'd speculate that it is a regular `href` attribute with a bunch of random characters prepended to it so that browsers will ignore it. i.e. `w3mir` is a pseudo-comment.